# how to put variables with data binding in the same line

Tags: knockout.js

I am new in knockoutjs and i want to put the variable with the text that i provided in the same line but I can't' find how to do it even if I put the CSS style, can anyone help me please without css style?

```
 <div>
  <p>Age :</p>
 <div> <!--ko text: (person_age) --><!-- /ko --><p>year(s)</p></div>
 </div>
```

the result for me by this code is :

```
Age :
20
years(s)
```

i want it like this :

```
Age :
20 years(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's pushing your string "years" down onto a new line is the paragraph tag wrapping the string. To get what you're after I would rewrite it like this:

```
<p><span data-bind="text:person_age"></span> years</p>
```

That way the value of `person_age` and "years" will be on the same line. The paragraph tag is what is called a "block level element" meaning it will display the contents as block. A span is what is called an inline element. Learn more about that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements.

Also notice that you're using knockout's "containerless syntax". I usually shy away from using that since you can accomplish most of what you need to do using the neater `data-bind` [attribute](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html). That way you can stick to using the regular HTML tags and not use the `<!--` and `-->` which I think the ko designers intend to be used as a last ditch strategy if using a tag would be ugly.